# Restrict/validate JavaScript code to a specific library

Tags: javascript, validation, object

I have a project where users can submit JavaScript code. However, I want to check, that inside the submitted code only methods and properties of a certain javascript object are used. e.g. my object's name is X, then users should only be allowed to use:

```
X.method1();
X.method2();
X.method3(X.propertyA);
if(X.booleanPropertyB)
{
    X.method(X.propertyWOW);
}
```

They should NOT be allowed to create new vars or use properties or methods of javascript objects like document, window or navigator.

What would be a good approach to validate the scripts according to these rules? Either inside JavaScript or by a server side validator e.g. written in Java.

So far my idea is to use a server side validator and check that the first non-whitespace characters after every semicolon as well as after every opening curly bracket are "X." or a reserved word like if, else, while, for etc

However, I think I'm over-simplifying it and would like to know your thoughts on whether this is a reasonable approach.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe a linter can help here, not sure.

Comment: If you're asking that, I would think twice more whether allowing users to submit arbitrary code is a good idea. You really need to know what you're doing to not screw yourself over.

Comment: Just as an example, I can run my code through http://www.jsfuck.com/ and overcome any text based protections you put in place.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I agree and thanks for the jsfuck example. I know the risks. But JavaScript is so convenient, with debuggers (firebug etc) available and many js engines. I was thinking about other scripting languages (groovy, python, lua), but none is so powerful, portable and widely known. I'll take all the answers here into account to find a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has two parts:

1. Make sure users use your object X

You can achieve this by mocking your object in tests and checking if relevant object methods are used. See [here](https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2014/03/27/mocks-in-jasmine-tests/) how it is done with Jasmine

2. Restrict users from accessing certain APIs
   The easy way to achieve it is to run the user code inside a closure. e.g.

   ```
   ;(function(window, document, console, eval, alert, setTimeout, setInterval){

   // run user code here
   // window, document etc. are inaccesible and null in this context
   })(null, null, null, null, null, null);
   ```

This, however, does not prevent users to declare their own stuff, vars, functions and alike.